# Reactjs with php backend on Heroku

Tags: php, reactjs, heroku

So the issue is that my php code is not running as php code, but is interpreted literally as though it was just a txt file.

My php code is:

```
<?

    echo "hi";

?>
```

and it's returning: `<?php echo "hi"; ?>`

I am calling my php file via:

```
  componentDidMount()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/test.php",
      success: (data) =>
      {
        this.setState({data});
      }
    });
  }
```

My php file is inside the public folder.

This also doesn't work locally with `npm start` even though I have php installed.

PS. If this isn't the right forum, I wouldn't mind being redirected

Comment: Is the php running on a server?

Comment: @DroidNoob TBH, I'm not too sure. I'm not that familiar with MacOS. I have turned on Apache. I'm running the `npm start`. Should I move the folder to wherever the apache is running?

Comment: php should be pre rendered using a php server. I'm not familiar with MacOS either. IMO you should try out some tutorials on how to set up a php api backend

Comment: @DroidNoob I've set up apache on linux before :X Damn Apple, always trying to be the oddball *shakes fist*.

Comment: Here's a tutorial. https://www.codeofaninja.com/2016/07/react-crud-tutorial.html. You should try frameworks like laravel or lumen BTW.

Comment: @DroidNoob Not what I need. This is a server issue. I've already made react apps previously. Just stupid MacOS has a really convoluted system

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in your webroot folder (If you're using MAC with MAMP this is the default path to webroot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/) and create a file named info.php inside that write `<?php phpinfo();?>` and access this file from your browser. Check the output and see if PHP is properly installed on your system.

Comment: I'm just using the default apache, I got php working in the default folder but can't get user directories working. Heroku is still an issue that I've forwarded to the dev team

Comment: Okay. BTW You stated that "My php file is inside the public folder." and your ajax call is calling test.php in php folder. Check that as well.

Comment: it's part of react. It's relative locations is based on inside the public folder

Comment: Try moving the files to where the apache's webroot is.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to try it tomorrow